# How to display powerpoint presentation as a slider in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slider

In my project I want to show a PowerPoint slide in html page like slider. I have uploaded PowerPoint file from create page.

I tried with iframe but it does not show any preview. If i link live site ppt link it shows but in straight not like slider.

Here is my iframe code.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={{td_url()}}/uploads/course/EmbeddedPowerpointExample.ppt&embedded=true" style="width:550px; height:450px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Please help me, how can i show PowerPoint slider in html page.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668a1d-2299-4af3-91e1-ae57af723a60

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy  in my project every time user upload ppt files and show files in view page after upload.i already seen that.